# The closest value to $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is a multiple choice among 1.6, 2, 1.2. So the approximation should be sufficiently accurate. The solution is 1.6 as can be verified using Taylor expansion. But Taylor expansion method takes too long and this is supposed to be answered quickly. I wonder what alternatives there are to approx integral question like this. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah but this is the GRE math sub exam so no calculator allowed. Must be done by establishing a lower and upper bound that can be evaluated by hand

Comment: Also note the integrand is singular at $0$, so those numerical integration methods won't work.

Comment: Please show us what result you got using Taylor series; at the moment your question does not have enough context and may soon be closed. Here's a hint: find the inverse function of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac1{3x}}$, and therefore the integral is simply $x_0+\int_{x_0}^\infty f^{-1}(x)\,dx$ where $x_0$ is the $x$-coordinate of the intersection point between $f^{-1}$ and the line $y=1$.

Comment: I'm not even 100% sure that integral converges.  Is there a typo?

Comment: It does. See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mmjygmemad) @Randall

Comment: There is no typo. @TheSimpliFire's method could work except that it is a better approximation to do left half with $1/3x$. But I still appreciate other methods if there is any.

Comment: @DanielLi I can write up an answer, only if you add more detail to your post on how you would do it. Even if it's the long way, the community still wants to see your efforts.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I didn't actually finish the computation as it is very long (though technically doable) and it is obviously not the point of this question.  If you are unfamiliar with using Taylor expansion to compute integral. See this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356707/approximation-for-integral-involving-a-square-root-of-a-polynomial?rq=1

Comment: @DanielLi It's not that I'm unfamiliar with it, it's just that I think you need to add more to your post than just 'I can't use Taylor series because it's too long'.

Comment: Exact value is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{\log{\left( 7-4 \sqrt{3}\right) }}{6}\approx1.593686504020856$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire But that is exactly the point. If that method is quick and easy I wouldn't have asked this question. I can use matlab symbolic toolbox or other tools to generate a complete analytic derivation and paste it here but that is not the point of this question at all.

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas Do you mind sharing your strategy?

Comment: @Daniel Li Change $x=\frac1t$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be the integrand in question. Then $f^{-1}(x)=\frac1{3(x^2-1)}$ which intersects the line $y=1$ at $\left(\frac2{\sqrt3},1\right)$. The integral is thus equivalent to $$I=\int_{\frac2{\sqrt3}}^\infty\frac1{3(x^2-1)}\,dx+\frac2{\sqrt3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac13\cdot\frac12\ln\frac{1-x}{x+1}\right]_{2/\sqrt3}^\infty+\frac2{\sqrt3}=\frac2{\sqrt3}-\frac{\ln(7-4\sqrt3)}6$$ where the last term comes from the area of the rectangle of length $\frac2{\sqrt3}$ and height $1$. Using $1.74>\sqrt3>1.73$ we get $$\frac{200}{174}-\frac{\ln0.04}6>I>\frac{200}{173}-\frac{\ln0.08}6\implies \frac{100}{87}+\frac{\ln25}6>I>\frac{200}{173}+\frac{\ln12.5}6$$ and this rules $1.2$ and $2$ out as $e^2<3^2=9$ and similarly for $e^3$. Therefore $1.6$ is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

First thought - standard numerical integration techniques. But then, we have a problem - the integrand $\sqrt{1+\frac1{3x}}$ blows up to $\infty$ at zero. It's a fairly weak singularity, but we need to neutralize it before numerical methods will have a chance. To do that, substitute $x=t^2, dx=2t\,dt$:
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1+\frac1{3x}}\,dx = \int_0^1 2t\sqrt{1+\frac1{3t^2}}\,dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt{4t^2+\frac43}\,dt$$
Now we can apply standard numerical integration techniques. Let $f(t)=\sqrt{4t^2+\frac43}$. We have $f(0)=\sqrt{\frac43}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\approx 1.15$, $f(1)=\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}}=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}\approx 2.31$, and $f\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt{\frac73}=\frac{\sqrt{21}}{3}\approx 1.53$. That gets us a trapezoid rule estimate of about $1.73$ and a midpoint rule estimate of about $1.53$, so the true integral should be between them. Weighting them as in Simpson's rule, we get an estimate for the integral of $1.60$. Right on.

That wasn't quite all in my head - I've got enough digits of $\sqrt{3}$ memorized for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, but $f\left(\frac12\right)$ called for a calculator-equivalent. I could have done it with some paper, or settled for $1.5$ from my head.

In any case, the real key is that substitution to neutralize the singularity. Once we've done that, pretty much anything will work.

Oh, and it is possible to find the integral exactly. The exact form doesn't make it easier to find a good estimate.